# What's the cleaner way to have translation of "inch" to Portuguese ("polegada", symbol "pol") when using siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

Isn't it declaring a new unit?

```
\DeclareSIUnit\polegada{pol}
```

Loading a `locale`? (I couldn't find Brazilian or Portuguese.)

Adding a translation? How can I do that?

---

Edition: image included to show Google automatic conversion of "pol^2".

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after: you've got the right line to define a new unit ...

Comment: I thought there possibly was a "translation" solution such that I could type \inch and it would be automatically written as "polegada (pol)" when I change the language/locale to Portuguese.

Comment: In general (certainly for SI units) the unit _symbol_ doesn't get 'translated' at all (they are _not_ abbreviations). You could use `translator` or similar if you wish, but this is certainly not a 'supported' approach.

Comment: It seems you're right. I've just found ISO 31-1 that sets "in" as the international symbol for "inch".

However, it is very common to see it written as "pol" here in Brazil, as in "lb/pol^2", probably because people here usually don't understand what "inch" or "in" means. On the other hand, "lb" is probably more natural to us than to anglophones, since "pound" is "libra" in Portuguese (like original Latin).

By the way, even Google (maybe only here) recognizes "pol^2" as the same as "in^2" and gives me automatic conversion.

Comment: It's more properly "lbf/pol^2" (pound-force per squared inch) that is sometimes used as "psi" here. See:
http://www.escoladavida.eng.br/mecflubasica/relacoes_entre_unidades_de_press.htm

Comment: @JosephWright Your point about symbols not being translated is good enough and I would accept it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general (certainly for SI units) the unit symbol doesn't get 'translated' at all (they are not abbreviations). You could use translator or similar if you wish, but this is certainly not a 'supported' approach.